# Random picture from class in button

Tags: c#, class, button, random

I have to make  a little game for school where you have flags of countries and their names (in a listbox (named lstCountries) for me) and you need to combine them to score points.

I want to get random flags in buttons which I create like this

```
//Buttons Row 1
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Button btnNew = new Button();
                btnNew.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230 + 110 * i, 100);
                btnNew.Name = "btnFlag";
                btnNew.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
                btnNew.TabIndex = 0;
                btnNew.Text = "";
                btnNew.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                btnNew.Click += new System.EventHandler(buttonToevoegen);
                Controls.Add(btnNew);
                aButtons.Add(btnNew);
            }
```

And I made a class named Country:

```
class Country
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Flag { get; set; }

        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
```

And I created the countries like this:

```
private void vlaggenDeclareren()
        {
            Country oAlbanie = new Country();
            oAlbanie.Name = "Albanie";
            oAlbanie.Flag = "Albanie.png";
            oAlbanie.Number = 0;
            lstLandVullen(oAlbanie);

            Country oAndorra = new Country();
            oAndorra.Name = "Andorra";
            oAndorra.Flag = "Andorra.png";
            oAndorra.Number = 1;
            lstLandVullen(oAndorra);

            //and so on..
        }
```

I thought I would be able to give each button a random number from 0-40 (have 40 flags and 20 buttons), and link that random number to countryname.Number

If someone would be able to help me out (even if it's a completely different way) that would be awesome..
We're supposed to do this in a group of 3 people but everyone's refusing to do anything so I'm doing this alone ..

Comment: so far everything looks fine. Now you want a routine setRandomFlags() which would: 1) create a list to collect the used flags and then 2) do for each button in your buttonlist: check & repeat if a new random index is not in the list and then use it to assign the button's flag&country (the latter maybe in the tag) and add the used up index/flag/country to the list.. Make sure you create the Random object outside of the loop!!

Comment: But how do I link the random number to the country's number?

Comment: Create a random index in the range of the country list length: `int rInd = R.Next(lstLandVullen.Count);` (until you find a new one) (assuming it is a List; try to avoid arrays when you can use a List!) - You can then use it like this: `foreach(Button btn in aButtons) { /*create index first, then..:*/ btn.Text = lstLandVullen[rInd].Name; etc.. incl. usedList.Add(rInd); }` - What exactly do you want to do with the country.number? It is not really needed with all objects so nicely in Lists.

Comment: Feel free to ask more or to add your effort to the question, so we can help make it work..!

Comment: Well I wanted to give each country a number and then when I make my button the button would get a random number from 0-40 and let's say germany gets number 7 and the button gets number 7 it would take the flag from germany and use it as a background image for that button

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what __will__ happen when you write out the above hints in code..

Comment: I don't really understand what you're telling me I should do, maybe I should start over again but I don't really see a way to do it in  a more simple way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74033/discussion-between-taw-and-jelle).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the  code to my comments:

From our chat I now know that you have a `ListBox lstLanden`, that you fill its `Items` with `Country` objects and that its `DisplayMember` is  and that `Country.Name`.

```
void setRandomFlag()
{
    // a random number generator
    Random R = new Random();
    // a list to keep our used up country numbers
    List<int> usedFlags = new List<int>();
    // the number of countries to chose from:
    int cCount = lstLanden.Items.Count;


    // first index we try
    int rInd = R.Next(cCount );
    // we shall give each button a flag etc..
    foreach (Button btn in abuttons)
    {
        // find an unsed index
        while (usedFlags.Contains(rInd)) {rInd = R.Next(cCount );}
        // store it
        usedFlags.Add(rInd);
        // pull the Country object from the listbox
        Country country = (Country)lstLanden.Items[rInd];
        // use it
        btn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(country.Flag);
        // this is a trick to keep a reference to the country at each button
        // we may need it later or not..
        btn.Tag = country;
    }
}
```

That should assign a flag and a `Country` object to each `Button`.

The next task will be to compare the Text of the `SelectedItem` in the `ListBox` with the `Name` of the `Button`'s `Country`.

For this create a **common** clicked event for all `Buttons`, cast the sender to `Button` and then its `Tag` to `Country`..

Comment: I can't count the list for some reason :/

Comment: Please join the chat! (See the last comment to the question!)